# how to copy property list file and its localized version to documents folder and make the system recognize the two version for a loclized application

Tags: iphone

i make a localized iphone application and in run time i want to modify the property list, so i at the first run of the application i copied the plist file but i don't sure if the copy operation also copied the localized version which the system store in a folder like: lp.fr
my quetion is: what i must do for the system to recognise the two files? should i make two directory in documents folder like lp.en and lp.fr and copy the two files?
also also xcode make the two plist with the same name, how i can determine every version and copy it?

i am waiting for some one to direct me to write way.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `NSBundle`'s [`pathForResource:ofType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBAHJF). It clearly states that it will return a non localized file if it exists or else pick a file in the order of user's language preferences. As you wan't to copy a localized resource, don't create a non localized copy and this will return the path for the most suitable resource. You can just copy that file and make changes to it.

If you are interested in getting the path to a resource of a specific language, take a look at [`pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIEBEBE).